# Is it possible to show a html element already on a page a second time without copying it?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a page with a hidden form containing several divs.

```
<form action="...">
    <div>
        <input id="menubar_open_article_bid" name="bid" onfocus="this.select();" onkeyup="do_v(); type="text">
        <a href="#"  onclick="return do_h();">
            Beitrag öffnen                              </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="menubar_open_article_cid" name="cid" onfocus="this.select();" onkeyup="do_a();" type="text">
        <a href="#" onclick="return do_y();">
            Container öffnen                                </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input  id="menubar_open_article_iid" name="iid" onfocus="this.select();" onkeyup="do_b();" type="text">
        <a href="#" onclick="return do_x();">
            Inhalt öffnen                               </a>
    </div>
</form>
```

As a first try i copied one of the divs using jQuery to another form in order to show it there (visible).
That worked great, but now the html element id is there twice.

I do not want to change that id. So a solution where i could only reffer to the div with id "`menubar_open_article_iid`" to show the html-element would solve my problem. Is that possible? (though i never heard of something like this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware, this is not possible.

I think the main problem here is that you want one input shown twice, but still being the same input. That is going to be problematic, and it is also bad interface design. The user is likely to be confused by having two separate but different inputs in a form.

I'd recommend you to not do this.

Comment: in my use case it would be ok, cause the hidden form which holds the div to be reffered to is not visible (problem here is that this hidden form is created using a complex mechanism and time is short now)

Comment: @Thariama: Are they separate forms? In that case it shouldn't be a problem to have the same id's, and your copying should work. Personally I'd make sure all fields are in the HTML output from the start, but if that's not feasible...

Comment: @Thariama: Good. Then there is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can leverage this approach:

I'd use jQuery and jQuery metadata:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata

In your hidden form, don't specify any id's. Instead, specify what you want the ids to be via **class metadata**:

```
<form class="hide form-to-clone">
    <div>
        <input class="setId {id:'id1'}" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="setId {id:'id2'}" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="setId {id:'id3'}" />
    </div>
</form>
```

In jQuery, clone the hidden form:

```
var clone = $('.form-to-clone').clone();
```

Then, loop through the elements in the clone and set the ids:

```
clone.find('.setId').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.attr('id', $this.metadata().id);
});
```

Then, append your cloned form to the page somewhere:

```
clone.show().appendTo('body');
```

Comment: hmm, we already use jQuery, but performance is an important issue - if possible i would like not to include additional js-scripts